# Show more information on hover in a new window as in facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

I want to show more information when a user hovers on a link like facebook shows the names and images of our friends who have liked a post when you hover over it. How can this be done? Can it be done using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course this can be done with JavaScript, there are several Plugins for those Tooltips:

- http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/
- http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/reference/
- http://designshack.net/articles/javascript/25-useful-resources-for-creating-tooltips-with-javascript-or-css/

You can put whatever info you want in those Tooltips.

Comment: thanks.. Can you help me with getting tooltips in ajax calls using the first link that you provided? I have edited the question and explained the problem.

Comment: i´ve never used tooltipser so far, but did you take a look at the "get started" section? > http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/#getting-started